# Google docs doesn't let me open a doc offline says ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, google-chrome, offline

I have gone to google drive and selected cogwheel -> settings -> checked "offline"

Within the document in its "offline status" button it says:

This document is ready for offline use
You can edit this document without an internet connection. Changes will save to Drive once reconnected.

If I go offline while editing it then go back online it works.

However I am supposed to be able to open that doc in a new tab when I'm offline and it will load.  Currently it just does the dinosaur.  Same with drive.google.com

```
No internet
Try:
* Checking the network cables, modem, and router
* Reconnecting to Wi-Fi
ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
```

On another computer it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's some kind of freaky timing thing.

Basically even though I have told google drive "sync: allow offline" and that doc says it's  "ready for offline" google drive doesn't actually allow for the "fresh tab open of an offline doc" for it.  For awhile.

After you first choose the setting sync checkbox, you have to wait...a few hundred megabytes as it downloads many docs, some of which you haven't used in years.

After that point (and there is no real notification of when it occurs if you happen to close drive.google.com tab after initially telling it to sync and the "setting up offline" bubble popped up) then new tab behavior magically starts working.

So if your internet connection is good and it's been awhile and it's still not working, try unchecking "sync", wait awhile, then check it again.  If that doesn't work, try clearing chrome's local cache: https://superuser.com/a/1593868/39364